# installation of 17.10 freezes on HP Pavillion Power 15-cb0xx

Tags: system-installation

I try to install ubuntu 17.10 on a HP Pavilion Power laptop 15-cb0xx with Windows 10. I disabled secure boot in BIOS.

I use a bootable USB which worked to install Ubuntu on other laptops, so the ISO is certainly not corrupted. I can select a language, but the installation freezes on one of the next screens before proper installation begins every time.

I find some other answers which refer to freezes during installation, but none seem to answer my problem.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: The Pavilion Power line of product typically come with a Nvidia graphics. You may need `nomodeset` during installation and first boot until the Nvidia graphics drivers are installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where can I apply this setting? In Windows? In the BIOS? Can I still use a bootable USB to install Ubuntu? (sorry, I hardly ever had to change settings in order to install Ubuntu)

Edit: I found this link, is this how I go about it: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Answer (score 5):

I successfully run Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS Desktop AMD64 alongside preinstalled windows 10 on a 15-cb070nz HP pavilion notebook. I needed to start linux with nomodeset:

- disable secure boot in bios
- boot ubuntu installation image from USB stick
- on bootmanager press e and then add "nomodeset" in front of "quiet splash", then CTRL+X
- Install ubuntu
- After installation remove USB stick and change boot order ubuntu first in BIOS
- once again: in bootmanager press e and then add "nomodeset" in front of "quiet splash", then CTRL+X
- When in desktop, enter terminal with CTRL+ALT+T, and edit that GRUB starts linux every time with nomodeset:

  - sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  - add nomodeset: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset", CTRL+X
  - sudo update-grub
  - reboot

After that you should be able to running ubuntu.

Comment: Two questions: "boot ubuntu installation image from USB stick" - do you boot it in "try ubuntu" mode or in "install ubuntu" mode?  And what is the bootmanager, is it a program run from ubuntu? Couldn't find it via search engine

Comment: Omg, found it. When choosing between "try" and "install", you press e.  \*_\* Bootmanager = the boot menu, in that case. Stupid me.