# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu freezing after installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, nvidia, windows-10

I've been trying since yesterday to dual boot my new HP Pavilion Power 15, but apparently there's something wrong with it. I've tried dual booting Windows 10 with both Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04. I followed this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives) more than once and without missing anything and everything seems to work fine until the installation ends and asks me to reboot. As I do that computer freeze (maybe there's a GPU problem?). I tried a forced shutdown, but it doesn't seems to work after that.

*PC Specs:*

Processor: Intel Core i7-7700HQ | 2.8 GHz - 6 MB L3
  HDD: 1000 GB
  SSD: 128 GB
  RAM: 8 GB
  Display: 15.6" WLED Full HD
  WiFi IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac
  Bluetooth 4.2
  Windows 10 Home 64-bit
  Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050, 2 GB

Comment: Have you tried disablign secure boot?

Comment: Yup. As I said I've strictly followed that guide.

Comment: What do you mean with "the computer freeze"? Can you press `ESC` during the boot process (when you see the Ubuntu logo) to see where the boot process stops?

Comment: I mean that as soon as it finishes the ubuntu installation it asks me to reboot the system. As I do that, as soon as I literally click "reboot now" it freezes.

Comment: At that point Ubuntu should be completely installed. Try shutting down the pc with the power button an then restart it.

Comment: So apparently it seems to be a bigger problem than I though it was. The freeze happens even if, for instance, I've just entered ubuntu installer and I'm deciding to exit. It's like every time I'm leaving the usb boot pc goes on a loop or something and blocks.

Comment: Enter the live image and try to shutdown from terminal launching `systemctl poweroff`. See if any error appears. (Try with `systemctl reboot` too).  However, is Ubuntu installed after restart?

Comment: So, I tryed with live image too. It seems to be installing everything fine. I tryed using sysrq REISUB method but ubuntu seems still really buggy. First power one after installation, I've entered Ubuntu but the screen was black and nothing happened. I used REISUB again and this time I could access desktop but after some really basic operations (in like 1 minute or so) it freezed again and had to force reboot once more. It doesn't seem to be working honestly. I'll try with systemctl and I'll let you know.

Comment: I tryed systemctl too. Same result. I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1694262) that but it's really old and obviously isn't working in my case but might lead to something since it could be related. There must be something not going along with ubuntu but I can't figure it out honestly.

Comment: OK I think I solved it and it was quite easy in the end. Check main question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation of 17.10 freezes on HP Pavillion Power 15-cb0xx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993354/installation-of-17-10-freezes-on-hp-pavillion-power-15-cb0xx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993354/installation-of-17-10-freezes-on-hp-pavillion-power-15-cb0xx)

So apparently my problem (but it may affects many more users) simply was that nvidia graphics were "getting in the way". A simple solution after spotting that has been adding in GRUB-edit (e-key right before going for "Live test") **nomodeset in front of quiet splash** and the ctrl+X to **temporally** save.
After that shutting down/rebooting was just a distant nightmare.

**UPDATE**: with Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) it was introduced with ubiquity installer a `safe graphics` mode that automatically activate the nomodeset option.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Ashwani you could read about the issue in more details here (https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/). It's a common issue for computers that relies on nvidia graphics since after installation the drivers are not installed automatically but the OS still points to them instead of safely fallback to the default ones. Just add `nomodeset` option before booting [like here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000123893/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting) or just select (`safe graphics`) at install time if you are on Ubuntu 20+ distros.

Comment: Then once you're able to boot without freezes or other issues, just install the recommended drivers under `Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers`.

Comment: Yes, I installed the Additional Drivers and changed the graphics to Nvidia, it seems to be working now. Thanks!!

Comment: Np. Glad I could help.