# Can't install Ubuntu 19.04 on HP Pavilion 15-bc450ns

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, hp, 19.04

I've been using ubuntu since years but I am very ignorant about all of it, so here I am:
I bought a new HP Pavilion with fullHD and I am having a lot of problems with installing ubuntu.

1st I tried with 19.04,but if freezes after few seconds or doesn't even charge.
So I've tried to install ubuntu 14 and update the system until arriving at the 19. It worked but the screen was in 800x600, so I had to change doc manually (all following random post and putting random lines in the terminal) and in grub I put manually 1920x1080. 
Everything was working but not the videos, so I followed more instruction I found in internet: I upgraded nvidia-driver-390. I did a reboot and nothing was working anymore. :( I am spending days trying to install ubuntu and I need your help! I guess the problem is the nvidia driver?
Is there a 19.04 version which is more compatible with HP Pavilions?
What should I do?

Here some details:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Dsv0000103Csd000084F8bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Comment: It is a driver problem. Here is a question similar to yours, try these solutions they give. Sure they help you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I've did everything again and i think that this helped: https://askubuntu.com/a/1023956/575044